# How can i use an optional argument in MySql Where Clause which only applies if column is not null?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select row from DB based on match with insert object, but in WHERE clause i need condition to only apply if for that column value is not null. So basically only compare column with column from insert row if column from comparison table is not null. I hope i explained clearly enough, sorry for bad English.

My Table looks something like this:

```
id | provider | provider_sub | region
1    2          200            3
2    3          null           5
3    3          301            8
4    4          409            null
5    5          null           null
```

the table above represents filters by which to categorize my insert object which are like these:

```
{provider:2,provider_sub:200,region:null} -> no matching row
{provider:3,provider_sub:null,region:5} -> matching with row 2
{provider:4,provider_sub:409,region:6} -> no matching row
{provider:5,provider_sub:7,region:2} -> matching with row 4
```

My attempt is like this:

```
SET @provider = 1;
SET @provider_sub = null;
SET @region = null;

SELECT * FROM pool_filter 
WHERE 
    provider = IF(provider IS NOT NULL, @provider, provider) AND
    provider_sub = IF(provider_sub IS NOT NULL, @provider_sub, provider_sub) AND


      region = IF(region IS NOT NULL, @region, region) AND
  COALESCE(@provider,@provider_sub, @region) IS NOT NULL;
```

I cant get it to work as expected because when querying with provider set to 5 and rest is null, its not selecting row 4 as i would expect? Why is that?

Comment: Now as I understood, you simply need to change your `=` with null-safe operator `<=>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that there could be `NULL` values on *either* side of the comparison.  Comparing `NULL` in SQL is different than for non `NULL` values.  Here is the query I would recommend:

```
SELECT *
FROM pool_filter 
WHERE 
    (provider = @provider OR @provider IS NULL) AND
    (provider_sub = @provider_sub OR @provider_sub IS NULL) AND
    (region = @region OR @region IS NULL);
```

Using this logic, each of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause would match if either the column and user variable were both non `NULL` and matched, *or* the user variable were `NULL`.  In the case of, e.g., a `NULL` value for `@provider`, then that condition would effectively drop out.

Comment: If i set provider to 3, it is not selecting row 3/4 as expected.

Comment: Reload your page.  I have flip-flopped a bit on my answer.